# I want to create a gcc macro named DEFAULT

Tags: c

In a file I am compiling with gcc, I have many instances of:

```
#ifndef VARIABLE_NAME
#define VARIABLE_NAME value
#endif`
```

I would like to define a macro to use like:

```
DEFAULT VARIABLE_NAME 44
```

I had hoped to use:

```
#define DEFAULT(v,x)   #ifndef v /#define v x /#endif
DEFAULT MAX_LIMIT 99
```

I had hoped for

```
#define MAX_LIMIT 99
```

Not surprisingly

```
d.c:2:25: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter #define DEFAULT(v,x)   #ifndef v /#define v x /#endif                         ^ d.c:4:1: error: unknown type name 'DEFAULT'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't really do that. The preprocessor directives are line-based. You can't have multiple on a single line.

Comment: Also, you don't really want to add macros to change the syntax of the language. That makes your code *too* unique, and no-one else would want to touch it. And if you use it too much then you'll make it a habit that will be hard to break out of, and making it harder for you to work on other projects.

Answer (score 3):

#### Diagnosis

In standard C, you can't do what you are seeking to do.

Even if the replacement text for a macro looks like a preprocessor directive, it is not treated as a preprocessor directive by the preprocessor.

C11 [§6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p3):

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below.

You're trying to have the preprocessor violate that rule.

#### Prescription

You could create a preprocessor (compiler, code generator) of your own.  Create a file — `defaults.pp` — containing the variables you want conditionally defined:

```
VARIABLE_NAME 44
MAX_LIMIT 99
ABSTRACT "opaque"
```

Create a shell script `define-defaults.sh` that converts that into a header:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#
# Define defaults from 'name value' pairs

echo '/* XXX: GENERATED FILE - do not edit */'
echo
[ -n "$*" ] && echo "/* Generated from $* */"
echo

sed -e 's/#.*//' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' "$@" |
while read -r name value
do
    echo "#ifndef $name"
    echo "#define $name $value"
    echo "#endif /* $name */"
    echo
done
```

The `sed` script removes blank lines and `#` comments from the input.

Use:

```bash
sh define-defaults.sh defaults.pp | tee defaults.h
```

Output:

```c
/* XXX: GENERATED FILE - do not edit */

/* Generated from defaults.pp */

#ifndef VARIABLE_NAME
#define VARIABLE_NAME 44
#endif /* VARIABLE_NAME */

#ifndef MAX_LIMIT
#define MAX_LIMIT 99
#endif /* MAX_LIMIT */

#ifndef ABSTRACT
#define ABSTRACT "opaque"
#endif /* ABSTRACT */
```

You then include `defaults.h` in your source code.  Keep `defaults.pp` (and the script) under source code control; `defaults.h` is a generated file and should not (normally) be under source code control.

You could add header guards and do other fancy processing in the script — I probably would.  But that works reasonably sanely.